# Connect to another Sql Server 2008 instance in a stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

Lets assume we have 2 instances of SQL Server. In the first instance I have a stored procedure that needs to connect to the second instance and run a query. Is it possible? How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Create a linked server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190479.aspx) and address it from within your stored procedure.

Comment: Thanks. I should know that .. :)